# Is it possible to detect that enter key is pressed without using key codes javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that I can do something like

```
function runScript(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

but I was wondering if there is some other way. Thanks!

Comment: you can do `if(13 == e.keyCode)` :P

Comment: you mean without scripting at all?

Comment: you can use `if(e.which == 13)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more readable can use:

```
function runScript(e) {
  if(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "a") {
     //Some code
  }
}
```